# How to run a piece of code at the moment after fixtures are loaded but before the first test started?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I use fixtures for my test data. I need to make extra initialization steps after my fixtures are loaded into db, but before any test run. The extra initialization data is supposed to be available to all the tests.

test_helper.rb

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test do
     # here I use my extra initialization data
     # it takes a lot of effort to create the data
     # I'd like this data is available to every test in initial state
   end
end
```

Here is the log. I marked the place where I need my initialization to be done.

```
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:19.910545 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (8.8ms)  ALTER TABLE "mytable" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:20.151100 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:20.153111 #94547] DEBUG -- :   Fixture Delete (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "mytable"
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.231062 #94547] DEBUG -- :   Fixture Insert (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "mytable" ...
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.234581 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.239761 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (4.1ms)  ALTER TABLE "mytable" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
# <-- I need my initialization here
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.256388 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
I, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.256510 #94547]  INFO -- : -----------------------------
I, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.256550 #94547]  INFO -- : DummyTest: test_my_dummy_test
I, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.256583 #94547]  INFO -- : -----------------------------
(dbg) my dummy test: setup
(dbg) my dummy test
(dbg) my dummy test: teardown
D, [2017-08-09T07:54:21.257013 #94547] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: You should add some code on how are you currently doing it. Otherwise is hard to know how to help you.

Comment: @Nobita I've added some code for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best found solution so far is to add the following method to ActiveSupport::TestCase class

```
def enlist_fixture_connections(*)
  result = super
  # you code here
  result
end
```

You code will be executed after fixture initialization and before each test but not in a test's transaction.